# fast-bert library in SageMaker giving "No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, bash, amazon-web-services, shell, bert-language-model

I'm trying to use python fast-bert library to load it to Amazon's SageMaker using their script in `container/build_and_push.sh` but then in SageMaker I receive error `/usr/bin/env: ‘python\r’: No such file or directory`.

I understand it's related to to Windows/Linux differences, but how can I get rid of it in this script, because I'm not familiar with shell at all :/ Thanks in advance!

```
https://github.com/kaushaltrivedi/fast-bert/blob/master/container/build_and_push.sh
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have the file /usr/bin/env - perhaps change the shebang to /bin/bash or /usr/bin/bash helps - although I'm wondering what the python\r is doing there....

Comment: Alter your editor to use "unix" style line endings (\n) instead of "DOS" style (\r\n)

Comment: See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: https://notepad-plus-plus.org